# Apache - AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2.4

I'm using apache for my system. Recently I received complaints from the client saying they unable to access the system. I remote to  my server and checks my Apache and its working fine. I try to launch the localhost ant it working fine also. I could not find any issue and have no other go rather than restarted my apache. After restarted the system back to normal. After some digging in the log files, I found something there.

> The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.

I try to google it out but unable to find the solution for this. Is there anyone face the same issue earlier and solve this. Below is my server details:

> Window Server 2008 R2 Standard
>   Apache 2.4
>   Using SSL Connection

Any advice or reference links for the issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

This usually occurs due to some software or driver inserting itself into the Windows network stack. You can skip over these layers by adding this to 2.4:

AcceptFilter https none

AcceptFilter http none

In older releases, this was turned off "Win32DisableAcceptEX".

Comment: after adding `Win32DisableAcceptEX` to the httpd.conf file, the syntax validation is failing; I was trying to follow options given in the [article:](https://techjourney.net/winnt_accept-asynchronous-acceptex-failed-error-in-apache-log/)

could any one please provide further info?

Comment: I confirm that it works and it's explained in the documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/AcceptExFailed

Comment: This did the trick for me. I was experiencing really odd server freezes on my developer test system, where Apache started refusing to handle any requests until certain other requests completed - honestly had no clue how it was happening until I spotted this error in the log. (Apache 2.4.x here.)